# spring JDBC connection issue with postgres

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc

I have an api in spring that performs crud operations on postgres db. after few insertions its trying to open a new jdbc connection and hangs for ever.

```
[DEBUG,StatefulPersistenceContext,main] initializing non-lazy collections
[TRACE,JDBCContext,main] after autocommit
[DEBUG,ConnectionManager,main] transaction completed on session with on_close connection      release mode; be sure to close the session to release JDBC resources!
[TRACE,SessionImpl,main] after transaction completion
[INFO,Initializer,main] Creating publisher user for lisa penny
[DEBUG,DefaultListableBeanFactory,main] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
[DEBUG,HibernateTransactionManager,main] Creating new transaction with name     [org.temp.demo.core.dao.hb.GenericHibernateDAO.makePersistent]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
[DEBUG,SessionImpl,main] opened session at timestamp: 13657283326
[DEBUG,HibernateTransactionManager,main] Opened new Session     
[org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl@3a1ca1a4] for Hibernate transaction
[DEBUG,HibernateTransactionManager,main] Preparing JDBC Connection of Hibernate Session   [org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl@3a1ca1a4]
[DEBUG,JDBCTransaction,main] begin
[DEBUG,ConnectionManager,main] opening JDBC connection
```

it stops here for every, can anyone suggest something please? I have no clue

Comment: Is it a web application? What happens when you restart the application? (I am assuming it will run again and after a few inserts will hang for ever again) Do you have any tool to check the open connections in you DBMS?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what's happening, when I restart, hangs after few inserts. It's a web application. Looks to me a threading issue or the previous transaction do not close properly. But sure how it works correctly for first few times. I have got pgAdmin3, what kinda tool do I need?

Comment: Do you know which transactions are hanging? Maybe, is hanging only when you trying to perform certain operations and therefore knowing what is causing the problem may help to solve your issue. Try something like: http://heatware.net/databases/how-active-sql-queries-open-connections-postgres/

Comment: I dont think its the data. I am not sure why it fails after few inserts.

Comment: Right, is probably not data related. But, likely to be Transaction/Session related. If the number of Transactions/Sessions increases a lot it will be definitely polling or not closed Transactions/Sessions. That is the reason why I suggested analyzing your DBMS first. If the number of Transactions/Sessions does not increase; then, your code might be falling in some sort of infinity loop/processing. Does it make sense for you?

Comment: Can you post where did you use transaction ? Which class and function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to close the Transaction and Session after doing operation. If not current session and transaction was opening and you opened the new transaction for new operation. That will cause your database hang.

Answer (score 0):

Close transaction and session example. Find your autowired class and change as my example.

```
public ContentResult insertNewContent( Content content )
    {
        ContentResult result = this.validateContent( content );

        if( result.hasErrors() == false )
        {
            Session session = this._hibernateSessionFactory.openSession();
            Transaction tx = null;

            try
            {
                //important !
                tx = session.beginTransaction();

                session.save( content );

                tx.commit();

                if( content.get_id() > 0 )
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    result.addError( ContentResult.CODES.ERROR_INVALID_ID );
                }

            }
            catch( HibernateException e )
            {
                //important !
                if( tx != null )
                {
                    tx.rollback();
                }
                ContentRepository.logger.error( "insertNewContent failed" );        
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                //important !
                session.close();
            }
        }

        return result;

    }
```